# The arguments ' to ' and ' from ' in vue router beforeEach function is not invoked, ESlint give me the warning ' 'to' is defined but never used '

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, eslint

I met a problem when using Vue Router beforeEach function.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  NPgrogress.start();
  next();
});
```

I only need the third argument in beforeEach, but ESlint give me the error

```
  145:19  error  'to' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
  145:23  error  'from' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

I don't want to turn off ESlint rule 'no-unused-vars' to 'off' or 'eslint-disable-next-line'.

Do we have any other solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest and most intuitive way is to set the rule for `no-unused-vars` to use `after-used` for `args`. This is the default though, so you likely did overwrite it somewhere. Using `after-used` will disable the check on any arguments of a function that occur before the last used argument. With this, the following code would not cause any issues:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  NPgrogress.start();
  next();
});
```

But the following code would (because `two` is defined, but never used, and you can just omit it from the parameter list.

```
function a(one, two) {
  console.log(one);
}
```

[Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#options) on eslint.org

Comment: wow, that is really what I need, thank you.